# Key 128bits, return array 16 bits

Tags: php, arrays, node.js

I detail the project:
I'm using an PHP SDK for mega.co.nz, but due the problem with the cryptography (the prepare_key is too slow, and occasionally causes an problem I describe as "false positive") I look an alternative for the login, and after much testing alternatives (python, c++, c#) with no experience, i found an sdk in nodejs and was unable to adapt for my needs.

The SDK is https://github.com/tonistiigi/mega/ and the problem is the next:

Node.JS returns an 16 bytes array while PHP returns 4 words(4 bytes each)

[image: Example]

How convert the array as returning me to nodejs otherwise?

Sorry for my english!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from node.js to PHP format:

```
buffer = require('buffer');

arr = [8,24,40,56,72,88,104,120,136,152,168,184,200,216,232,248];
console.log(arr.length);
buff = new Buffer(arr);
console.log(buff);

phpstreq = [];
phpinteq = [];
length = 4;
count = 0;
while (count < 16)
{
    phpinteq.push(buff.readUInt32BE(count,true))
    phpstreq.push(buff.slice(count,count+length));
    count += length;
}
console.log(phpinteq);
console.log(phpstreq);
```

Output for above

```
[ 135800888, 1213753464, 2291706040, 3369658616 ]
[ <Buffer 08 18 28 38>,
  <Buffer 48 58 68 78>,
  <Buffer 88 98 a8 b8>,
  <Buffer c8 d8 e8 f8> ]
```

To convert from PHP to node.js format:

```
<?php
$arr = [ 135800888, 1213753464, 2291706040, 3369658616 ];
$bytearray =[];

foreach ($arr as $byte4)
{
    $eq = unpack("C*", pack("N", $byte4));
    $bytearray = array_merge($bytearray,$eq);
}

print_r($bytearray);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 40
    [3] => 56
    [4] => 72
    [5] => 88
    [6] => 104
    [7] => 120
    [8] => 136
    [9] => 152
    [10] => 168
    [11] => 184
    [12] => 200
    [13] => 216
    [14] => 232
    [15] => 248
)
```

I have used big endian formats above. Since you fuzzied your output, you will have to check it yourself. Also take care that you validate the input arrays used in node.js. In node.js integer `x` in array must be `0 < x < 256` (remember each number = 1 byte).

Comment: Nice, thanks! thats works perfect with the "u_k", but with the "u_privk" i have a problem. In PHP is an array of 4, an the array[0] have 320 length, array[1] have 320 length, array[2] have 628 length and array[3] have 318 length, NODE.JS returns an multidimensional with an array size 4 what in array[0] size 37, array[1] size 37, array[2] size 74, array[3] size 37. Idea?

Comment: @Bayer The conversion was clear for the example you had shown. The size was same for both case. Can you show this in an example (hide the necessary details if you want). I have not seen this before.

Comment: you can view the arrays here: http://pastebin.com/28eSdVGC i need show the nodejs array as php ._., thanks for your help

Comment: Certainly, if it helps, the privk comes of RSA in NODE.JS and in PHP is parsed with the function a32_to_str.

Comment: According to MEGA RSA public/private keys (2048 bit: 348/875 characters)